# Best way to display the skeleton from Kinect on an active PowerPoint-Presentation?

Tags: c#, add-in, powerpoint, slideshow, kinect

I display the skeleton from kinect on an active PowerPoint-Presenatation. My question is, is there a better way to do this, because it´s very slow and I think there could be a better solution :-)

```
List<Shape> shape = new List<Shape>();

foreach (SkeletonData data in skeletonFrame.Skeletons)
{
  if (SkeletonTrackingState.Tracked == data.TrackingState)
  {
     //get the actual slide
     Slide slide = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Slide;

     //delete old shapes (lines)
     shape.ForEach(s => s.Delete());
     shape.Clear();

     //get new points
     Point head = getDisplayPosition(data.Joints[JointID.Head]);
     Point shoulder = getDisplayPosition(data.Joints[JointID.ShoulderCenter]);
     Point shoulderleft = getDisplayPosition(data.Joints[JointID.ShoulderLeft]);
     Point shoulderright = getDisplayPosition(data.Joints[JointID.ShoulderRight]);
     Point elbowright = getDisplayPosition(data.Joints[JointID.ElbowRight]);
     Point elbowleft = getDisplayPosition(data.Joints[JointID.ElbowLeft]);
     Point wristright = getDisplayPosition(data.Joints[JointID.WristRight]);
     Point wristleft = getDisplayPosition(data.Joints[JointID.WristLeft]);
     Point handright = getDisplayPosition(data.Joints[JointID.HandRight]);
     Point handleft = getDisplayPosition(data.Joints[JointID.HandLeft]);

     //add new shapes (lines)
     shape.Add(slide.Shapes.AddShape(MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeCloud,(float)head.X, (float)head.Y, 10, 10));
     shape.Add(slide.Shapes.AddLine((float)head.X, (float)head.Y, (float)shoulder.X, (float)shoulder.Y));

     shape.Add(slide.Shapes.AddLine((float)shoulder.X, (float)shoulder.Y, (float)shoulderright.X, (float)shoulderright.Y));
     shape.Add(slide.Shapes.AddLine((float)shoulderright.X, (float)shoulderright.Y, (float)elbowright.X, (float)elbowright.Y));
     shape.Add(slide.Shapes.AddLine((float)elbowright.X, (float)elbowright.Y, (float)wristright.X, (float)wristright.Y));
     shape.Add(slide.Shapes.AddLine((float)wristright.X, (float)wristright.Y, (float)handright.X, (float)handright.Y));

     shape.Add(slide.Shapes.AddLine((float)shoulder.X, (float)shoulder.Y, (float)shoulderleft.X, (float)shoulderleft.Y));
     shape.Add(slide.Shapes.AddLine((float)shoulderleft.X, (float)shoulderleft.Y, (float)elbowleft.X, (float)elbowleft.Y));
     shape.Add(slide.Shapes.AddLine((float)elbowleft.X, (float)elbowleft.Y, (float)wristleft.X, (float)wristleft.Y));
     shape.Add(slide.Shapes.AddLine((float)wristleft.X, (float)wristleft.Y, (float)handleft.X, (float)handleft.Y));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a performant solution is to put a window(form) in front of the presentation (alway on front) and stream/paint your data to this window.